# Missing urwid on OS X Lion Python 2.7

Tags: python, urwid

I installed [mitmproxy](http://mitmproxy.org/) this morning and I started seeing this in my console:

ImportError: No module named urwid

After a bit of Googling I found [a post](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=importerror%3a%20no%20module%20named%20urwid&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCMQFjAA&url=http://forum.tinycorelinux.net/index.php?topic=6975.0&ei=yuQzT6LcNa3ZiQKIx-DECg&usg=AFQjCNF71OKCV6EYfb14Xy-F3uGm8cg-6w) on the TinyCoreLinux forum that implies there may have been a hiccup with the urwid module between versions 2.6 and 2.7. I don't use Python often enough to understand how to manage its dependencies. Could somebody shine some light on what I would do to fix the missing urwid module on my system? I'm running OS X Lion with Python 2.7.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to http://excess.org/urwid/ and download the link titled "Download Latest Stable Version: urwid-X.X.X.tar.gz".

Once you download it, unzip the file.

Open the terminal and change to the unzipped directory.  Probably something like 
`cd ~/Downloads/urwid-X.X.X`

Run the install script with `sudo python setup.py install`

It should compile and install, and then `mitmproxy` should run fine.

Answer (score -1):

or you can build tar distribution from setup.py --help-command: setup.py dist - this will will build tar in "dist" folder from bin folder of that tar you can run pip install pudb - this will include urwid and other dependency